# How to create few users for mongodb in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a nodejs app with redis and mongodb and I need to create a few init user for mongodb. I know how to create the root user:

```
mongo:
image: mongo:latest
env_file: .env
environment:   
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
  MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}
```

How to create one more user in docker-compose or in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done this way. This is by design.

There's a walk around though, mount a shell script (file name ending with `.sh`) or a javascript script (file name ending with `.js`) inside the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` and it will get executed on runtime. Using it  create as many users as you want.

See how to [initialize a fresh instance](https://store.docker.com/images/mongo).